# Rabbit MQ handle cancellation token

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am following this article (http://www.jarloo.com/listening-to-rabbitmq-events/) for consuming the messages on a console application, currently i am concerned about what happens when a user pressing CTRL + C and quits the application.

As a minimum i would prefer it complete processing the current message and ack before exiting the program. I am confused how can i implement this code as i am new to RabbitMQ.

I understand that channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer); is blocking thread.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: Will I not be processing the same message twice if I have not acknowledged the message when user pressed ctrl + c.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I managed to achieve but not sure if it is best way around or there is an improvement. I did not use the cancellationToken as yet not sure if we can use it.

On my console i get the expected result (see screenshot)

[image]

```
public abstract class QueueConnection : IDisposable
{
    internal IConnection _connection;
    internal IModel _model;
    internal IBasicProperties _properties;
    internal RabbitMQSettings _settings;
    internal protected object _modelLock = new Object();

    public QueueConnection(IOptions<RabbitMQSettings> queueConfig)
    {
        _settings = queueConfig.Value;
    }

    internal bool CreateModel(string queueName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queueName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The queue name has to be specified before.");
        }

        lock (_modelLock)
        {
            if (!IsConnected) Connect();
            if (_model == null || _model.IsClosed)
            {
                _model = _connection.CreateModel();

                // When AutoClose is true, the last channel to close will also cause the connection to close. 
                // If it is set to true before any channel is created, the connection will close then and there.
                _connection.AutoClose = true;

                // Configure the Quality of service for the model. Below is how what each setting means.
                // BasicQos(0="Dont send me a new message untill I’ve finshed",  1= "Send me one message at a time", false ="Apply to this Model only")
                _model.BasicQos(0, 50, false);

                const bool durable = true, queueAutoDelete = false, exclusive = false;

                _model.QueueDeclare(queueName, durable, exclusive, queueAutoDelete, null);
                _properties = RabbitMQProperties.CreateDefaultProperties(_model);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = _settings.HostName,
            UserName = _settings.UserName,
            Password = _settings.Password,
        };


        if (_settings.Port.HasValue) connectionFactory.Port = _settings.Port.Value;
        if (_settings.Heartbeat.HasValue) connectionFactory.RequestedHeartbeat = _settings.Heartbeat.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settings.VirtualHost)) connectionFactory.VirtualHost = _settings.VirtualHost;


        _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return _connection != null && _connection.IsOpen; }
    }

    public object GetConnection()
    {
        return _connection;
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_connection != null) _connection.Dispose();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Disconnect();
    }
}
```

QueueConsumer Class

```
public class QueueConsumer : QueueConnection, IQueueConsumer
{
    private EventingBasicConsumer consumer;
    public QueueConsumer(IOptions<RabbitMQSettings> queueConfig)
        :base(queueConfig) {}

    public void ReadFromQueue(Action<string, ulong> onDequeue, Action<Exception, ulong> onError)
    {
        ReadFromQueue(onDequeue, onError, _settings.QueueName);
    }

    public void ReadFromQueue(Action<string, ulong> onDequeue, Action<Exception, ulong> onError, string queueName)
    {

        CreateModel(queueName);

        consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_model);

        // Receive the messages
        consumer.Received += (o, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var queueMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body);
                onDequeue.Invoke(queueMessage, e.DeliveryTag);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                onError.Invoke(ex, e.DeliveryTag);
            }
        };

        // if the consumer shutdown reconnects to rabbitmq and begin reading from the queue again.
        consumer.Shutdown += (o, e) =>
        {
            CreateModel(queueName);
            ReadFromQueue(onDequeue, onError, queueName);
        };

        _model.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

    }

    public void AcknowledgeMessage(ulong deliveryTag)
    {
        if (!IsConnected) Connect();
        CreateModel(_settings.QueueName);
        _model.BasicAck(deliveryTag, false);
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        _model.BasicCancel(consumer.ConsumerTag);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
    static ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}] -> Worker role started");

        var listener = serviceProvider.GetService<IMessageProcessor>();

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eArgs) =>
        {
            listener.OnStop();

            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}] -> Worker role finished");
            _quitEvent.Set();
            eArgs.Cancel = true;
        };

        _quitEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        // Build appsetting.json configuration
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment");

        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

        // Support typed options
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<RabbitMQSettings>(configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQConfig"));

        services.AddSingleton<IQueueConsumer, QueueConsumer>();
        services.AddScoped<IMessageProcessor, MessageProcessor>();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the issue you are trying to get around only thing I can think of is treat this as a transaction.. Only when you get the message, process it completely and send the Ack back consider the transaction as completed.

If you process the message first and some one terminates the application before the Ack it will get queued again and when we restart the application it will get processed again.

Against that if you Ack first and then try to process the message  and some one terminates the application you will lose the message.

So looks like considering the whole process as transaction will make it work or the other option is to take care of same message getting processed again.

Comment: The problem is when I process the message I need to call an external service to update stuff so someone terminate the application I wanted to hold the termination and complete the processing that message I.e. Gracefully terminate.